# How to Merge DataGridView Column in Winforms

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I'm creating a winform application and have twos columns: Edit and Delete. How do i merge two columns become one in Datagribview?

[image: This is my current datagribview]

this is my expected datagridview

[image: This is my expected datagribview]

Datasource is a DataTable

Please give me any solutions!
Thank you so much

Comment: How should that merged column look like ? What is the datasource of this DataGridView ? Where is your code ? Please help us help you and provide us with more information, as it stands your question is to vague

Comment: You need to create custom datagridview cell for this. Or remove header text of "Edit" and "Delete" columns, and it will looks like one column. If you plan to have more custom UI solutions, then consider to switch to WPF or use WPF controls in the Winform.

Comment: @GuidoG I did update my question, please check it again!!

Comment: @Fabio Thank you for your solutions, it's really helpful to me!!

Comment: Unfortunately, the default .NET `DataGridView` is lacking in the cell merge area. However, there are many other third-party options. If you are forced to use a `DataGridView` and you don’t necessarily want to roll your own `DataGridViewColumn` control or dive into the grids paint event, have you considered overlaying a `Label` or panel on top of the two columns? I am confident a precisely placed `Label` with the same back color will give the same effect with a minimal amount of effort. Just a thought.

Comment: @JohnG Thank you for give me an another great solution. I will consider using it